# Confused about serverside rendering using React

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

I'm running a django application.  My setup of choice is this;

Have Django handle my api, routing and views but only send a barebones template to the user which will have the React files to load the DOM once it reaches the client.

This particular setup seems to work really well in that the user is immediately greeted with a page, although empty except for header, footer etc.. (inherited from a masterpage) it's content is then filled up via React scripts.

I'm failing to see why I need to render React on the server for anything other than SEO issues which hopefully will become less and less as we move into an all JavaScript world.

Am I misunderstanding a benefit other than SEO for doing something different than my current setup?

Comment: Some might suggest that having the page show with the data already rendered is a better user experience. But, that depends on the web server building and returning the page very fast. Many users may have little patience for a delay and would rather see progress.

Comment: React on the server is primarily for SEO.  I've seen some setups where the backend pipes down some HTML and some bridge code is used to initialize a new component on the go but it's often rare and situational, mostly for cached elements to skip DB queries.

Comment: Rendering on the server also makes JavaScript support optional. F.ex you can safely skip react/js rendering for legacy browsers and still provide a decent experience

Comment: Thanks for the response, hopefully we'll see less and less JavaScript disabled browsers.  I hope anyways.  For now on my particular project I'll skip this and hope for the best with SEO.  I've read articles from Google as of last year saying they are now indexing JavaScript, I'm not sure how well they are doing this though.